# How to maintain selected items in a cookie between pages? Each page is overwriting the contents from the previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a many pages, each of which has checkboxes on them. When a user clicks a checkbox on a page, it writes a value (a share class ID) to a `basket`. The `basket` is then written to a cookie to be retrievable between pages & page refreshes.

The user should only be allowed to write a maximum of 5 shareclasses to the cookie. If the user tries to add more, they are alerted, and the checkbox is unchecked.

This is all managed by a script that intercepts the click, which is loaded with each page.

The problem is that I'm getting inconsistent results. If I load pageA and pageB together, and then click a checkbox in pageA the shareclass is added to the basket and written to the cookie. If I then click a checkbox in pageB, the cookie is overwritten with the shareclass of the second page. Clicking another shareclass on pageA overwrites the cookie with the 2 I have clicked in pageA, and if I then click another shareclass in pageB, the cookie (now containing 2 shareclasses from pageA) is overwritten with the 2 shareclasses from pageB.

It appears that a `basket` object exists for each page that is loaded, and the contents of each is what determines the contents of the cookie. How can I make it so that there is only 1 global `basket` object between all pages?

The following code runs on each page load.

```
var basket = {};

jq15(document).ready(function ($) {
    initialiseCookieKeepAlive();

    $('.fund-compare-check-box').live('click', function () {

        if (basket[$(this).val()]) { 
            // if the basket already contains a Share Class, remove it
            RemoveShareclassFromBasket($, $(this).val());

        } else {

            var cookie = getCookie("fund_basket"); // get the cookie
            if (cookie) { // the cookie isn't empty
                if (cookie.split(".").length < 5) { 
                    // if the basket isn't full, add the share class
                    basket[$(this).val()] = $(this).val();
                } else {
                    alert("You have selected the maximum number of share classes");
                    return false;
                }
            } else { // the cookie is empty, so just add the share class
                basket[$(this).val()] = $(this).val();
            }
        }

        // when I've added or removed the share class, 
        // I want to replace the cookie with
        // the latest contents of the basket.
        WriteBasketToCookie();
    });
});

function initialiseCookieKeepAlive() {

    // this function is because they want the basket to last as long
    // as they have any of the relevant pages open, but not
    // the other pages in the site. That's why I didn't create a 'session' cookie

    keepCookieAlive("fund_basket");
    setInterval(function () {
        keepCookieAlive("fund_basket");
    }, 5 * 1000);
}

function keepCookieAlive(cookie) {
    if (getCookie(cookie)) {
        document.cookie = cookie + "=" + getCookie(cookie) + ";expires=" + getTime() + ";path=/";
    }
}


function RemoveShareclassFromBasket($, shareClassId) {
    delete basket[shareClassId];
    WriteBasketToCookie();
}

function WriteBasketToCookie() {
    var arr = new Array();
    for (shareClass in basket) {
        if (!isNaN(shareClass)) {
            arr.push(basket[shareClass]);
        }
    }

    document.cookie = "fund_basket=" + arr.join('.') + ";expires=" + getTime() + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

function ReCheckBoxes($) {
    if (getCookie("fund_basket")) {
        var cookie = getCookie("fund_basket").split(".");
        $('.fund-compare-check-box').attr('checked', false);

        for (var idx in cookie) {
            basket[cookie[idx]] = cookie[idx];
        }

        $('.fund-compare-check-box').each(function () {
            for (var idx in cookie) {
                if (cookie[idx] == $(this).val()) {
                    $(this).attr('checked', true);
                }
            }
        });
    } else { $('.fund-compare-check-box').attr('checked', false); }
}

function getTime() {

    var today = new Date();
    today.setTime(today.getTime());

    var expires = 20 * 1000;
    var exdate = new Date(today.getTime() + (expires));

    return exdate.toUTCString();
}
```

Comment: just read basket cookie and if it is not null append the new value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Had kind of the same problem this week. I had to store an array of data within my cookie. Here's how I did it. Please mind that i'm using the jquery $.cookie plugin (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
var ArrayCookie = function () {
    var cookieName = 'your_cookie_name_here';
    var cookie = $.cookie(cookieName, { path: '/' });
    var store = (cookie) ? JSON.parse(cookie) : [];

    return {
        add: function (title, text) {
            var new_Item = {
                title: title,
                text: text
            };
             store.push(new_Item);
             this.save();
        },
        remove: function (index) {
            store.splice(index, 1);
            this.save();
        },
        count: function () {
            if (this.list() == null || this.list().length < 1)
                return 0;
            return this.list().length;
        },
        list: function () {
            return store;
        },
        save: function () {
            $.cookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(store), { path: '/' });
        }
    };
};
```

**example:**

```
var cookie = new ArrayCookie();
cookie.list();                                  // returns the array
cookie.remove(1);                       // remove's item on index 1
cookie.add('title', 'some text');       // add's new item
```

For IE you also need to include this javascript file to support json
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js